# Keyboard Extension - Text direction right to left (RTL)

Tags: ios8

In a Keyboard Extension, there is a field in the `info.plist` "PrefersRightToLeft", which is a `Bool`. This (as far as I can tell) cannot be set programatically.

There is nothing in the `UITextInputTraits` or `UIKeyInput`delegate or any other way I tried. Tried to use the `setBaseWritingDirection`of the passed `UITextInput`.

Is there any way to have the textField change direction (RTL and LTR) from code to support the appropriate languages?

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution for this ? On my side I'm also facing similar problem **RTL** really starts to act when for example I've used arabic letters, but with Latin letters only the alignment changes.

Comment: @deimus No solution yet. Some textfields are 'auto detecting' (like Notes), but many others do not.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it seems like I'm going to need 2 separate apps to support both RTL and LTR languages.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 We did thought about creating a separate app for RTL languages. Biggest issue is, that users would want to easily switch back and forth between languages in the same app. It's really too bad since Apple has this function but it's 'hardcoded' into a 'read-only' param.

Comment: Have you thought about having multiple keyboard targets?

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 Actually I have not. Sounds interesting. However, let alone Apple approving such a move, we will still not have control over navigating between them. In other words, the user will still have to leave our keyboard and (we 'hope') go to 'our' other language. But, having left our keyboard, he can go anywhere else really.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that appropriate textFields are auto detecting the inserted language and adjust appropriately.